# How to run a function only on startup?

Tags: c#, startup

I have a desktop application written in C#, which I want o run at start-up.
 Moreover there is a function,

```
    Index()
```

which should run only once per start-up.
What I mean is that this function should be invoked in such a way that It runs only when the application starts at upstart and not when user starts the application manually. I want to know, how can I do this? I haven't been able to think of a fruitful logic for this problem, despite many efforts. My desktop application will run on windows 7.

Comment: It may depend upon the operating system. On Linux a nice trick is to use a `@reboot` entry for `crontab` (or some service script in `/etc/init.d/` etc etc). I have no idea about Windows.

Comment: @user65439 I don't think you're reading the question correctly

Comment: Use a command line parameter that's used when running it at startup. e.g. `c:\path\myapp.exe -startup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible easy attempt at a solution would be a command line parameter to which you can attach the "special" logic you need to run. When users then launch the application manually, this "magic" parameter won't be there, and the logic won't take place.

In a Console Application, all you need to do is check the `args` parameter of the `Main()` method.

To enable command-line arguments in the Main method in a Windows Forms application, you must manually modify the signature of Main in program.cs. The code generated by the Windows Forms designer creates a Main without an input parameter. You can also use Environment.CommandLine or Environment.GetCommandLineArgs to access the command-line arguments from any point in a console or Windows application.

Quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cb20e19t.aspx) which contains as usual a lot of info.

Comment: I have understood the logic provided by you, but how can i check whether the application launched at start-up or was launched normally? I need this for the "magic" parameter

Comment: When you define the startup action which fires up the application, provide the "magic" parameter yourself. That's the indication you're going to use in the application to know that it's being launched at startup. "Normal" launch won't have this parameter so your application will know it's not running at start-up.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to check that the app has been started at computer startup. A possible solution is to pass a command-line argument like `/startup`, and check for this parameter when the app starts.